# Replace array value if equal to another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to copy over a specific array index from array A to array B if both arrays are equal

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(5, 4))
B = a.copy()
B[0,0] = 10
B[:,3] = 999
```

**B:**

```
array([[ 10,   0,   4, 999],
       [  4,   3,   2, 999],
       [  1,   4,   3, 999],
       [  1,   3,   1, 999],
       [  3,   1,   1, 999]])
```

**A:**

```
array([[0, 0, 4, 3],
       [4, 3, 2, 2],
       [1, 4, 3, 2],
       [1, 3, 1, 4],
       [3, 1, 1, 3]])
```

now if `A[:,0:3] == B[:,0:3]` I want to replace `B[:,3] with A[:,3]`

like

```
array([[ 10,   0,   4, 999],
       [  4,   3,   2, 2],
       [  1,   4,   3, 2],
       [  1,   3,   1, 4],
       [  3,   1,   1, 3]])
```

Comment: `np.where((A[:, 0:3] == B[:, 0:3]).all(1), A[:, 3], B[:, 3])`. Just assign it back as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.copyto` with the `where` keyword:

```
np.copyto(B[:,3],A[:,3],where=(A[:,:3]==B[:,:3]).all(1))
B
# array([[ 10,   0,   4, 999],
#        [  4,   3,   2,   2],
#        [  1,   4,   3,   2],
#        [  1,   3,   1,   4],
#        [  3,   1,   1,   3]])
```